# How to use tf.py_func in keras lambda layer to wrap python code. ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined. Found None

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, lambda, layer

I would like to wrap numpy codes using tf.py_fucn in a customized lambda layer using keras.

Notice: only for simplicity I'm showing a simple np.power function.

Here is what I've done

```
def my_func(x):

    return np.power(x, 2)

def my_lambda_func(x):

    return tf.py_function(my_func, [x], tf.float32)


def model():

    inp = Input(shape=(2,))
    x = Dense(128)(inp)
    x = Dense(128)(x)

    z = Lambda(my_lambda_func)(x)

    output = Dense(1)(z)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)

    return model



model = model ()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Then I get this error

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
21
22
---> 23 model = model ()
24 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in build(self, input_shape)
1179     last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])
1180     if last_dim is None:
-> 1181       raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
1182                        'should be defined. Found `None`.')
1183     self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: last_dim})

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the output shape of the Lambda layer z, the tf.py_function would give None as output shape which does not sit well with the Dense layer that follows it. You should try:

z = Lambda(my_lambda_func)(x)

z.set_shape(x.shape)